# How to check Payment failure for Paypal Express Checkout

Tags: paypal, recurring-billing

We are using Paypal recurring billing service (using **Express Checkout**) at our website for monthly subscription. 
Since we have an *Australian account* so we are not able use the DPRP (Direct Payment Recurring Payment) service offered by Paypal because it seems, DPRP service is limited
to **only few countries** (US, UK and Canada).

In Express checkout payment details are received at *Paypal Website*. So **we do not have any information**, whether the payment failed, user pressed the Back button in browser or He/She intentionally clicked the cancel payment.

After speaking to Paypal support team we get know that there could be **multiple possible reason for Payment failure**, and seller has to contact Paypal by themself. So we **can
not provide any troubleshooting** for that at our website.

So we want to know, *Is there any possible solution to avoid this* or atleast can we *diffrentiate between the user for whom payment failed and who intentionally moved to
our website back* without doing payment because this way we are not only unable to followup with them but also loosing a part of the customer base, interested in our service.

Any help in this is Appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the Pay Pal IPN (Instant Payment Notification).

You configure the IPN url address on your PayPal merchant account settings. This page is simple HTML page with server-side programming that is listening for requests coming from PayPal.

There's no need to do something extra in the checkout process for making IPN work. Once you set this up, it will automatically work.

Every time something happens with a transaction in your merchant account, e.g. transaction completed/failed/canceled, PayPal will send an HTTP Post to your IPN listener URL.

Here you can get all the relevant information about the transaction, like the payer ID, the payment status. With this information you can decide what to do with your customer's order.